# Django cannot find __init__.py in the project folder when creating a new app

Tags: python, django, command-line, backend, server-side

Everything is set up. Inside the apps folder and the project folder inside the project there is an:

```
__init__.py
```

I double-checked to make sure the underscores are correct.

I am trying to create a new app using python `../manage.py startapp {{blogs_app}}`
but I keep getting the error messages:

```
Syntax Error: invalid syntax
cannot find the file sample_project/sample_project/__init__.py
```

Comment: The error message does not sound like a Syntax Error. Please add the full error traceback to your question. And the related code.

Comment: I assume that the double dot in ```../manage.py``` is a typo? Not sure if that's related.

Comment: that ../manage.py is the directory in which the file is located.